# how to handle row doubleclicking on GridView, and how to get the selected row

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gridview

I am working on a MVC application. My requirement is as below.

1. Add/Edit/ Delete functionality (done this using editor template). Done
2. Display read-only information on double click of row. - Need Solution.
3. Delete selected row in button click

Description: The user should be able to view the details  of a row by double clicking the row. Double clicking the row should display the details in read-only mode.

Then the other problem is how can i be able to select a row and delete it by button click.

Please let me know how I can achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 3):

Usually something like is achieved with javascript/jQuery.

You would bring down the read-only data when the page is first loaded but hidden from view.  Then set it up so that when you double click a row the extra information is displayed through modifying the CSS display value.

It would be equally as easy to show this information in another window - or wherever else you desire.

For more information take a look at the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) website